# Where is Active Directory configuration information stored?

Tags: mac, active-directory

I'm curious as to where Active Directory configurations are stored on Mac OS X 10.6. "man dsconfigad" and "man dscl" are both silent on where those utilities store/read their information.

In particular, I want to find where the AD binding authentication information is stored (hopefully securely?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config info for the Active Directory connector is all in /Library/Preferences/DirectoryService, in a bunch of files with names starting with "ActiveDirectory".  The one with the bind info has file permissions set so only root can read it.  There's also some related info in other files (e.g. that the AD connector is enabled, and its inclusion in the search policies), but most of it's right there.